# 2D-vector to linear memory in major column format

Tags: c++, stdvector, transpose

I have a variable declared as

```
vector<vector<float>> a(10, vector<float>(20));
```

what I am trying to do is to save the data but in a linear array that is transposed

```
float *linear = new float[200];
```

so in the end instead of having 10 rows of 20 elements (I've already implemented it) in the linear array have 20 rows of 10 elements.

Is there a better way to do this instead of copy from vectors to linear array and then transpose the linear array?

Comment: According to the other question, no, there is not a easy, efficient way to do this.

Comment: Transposition requires rearrangement unless you have a flag that controls whether you matrix is row- or column-major - in that case you can just toggle the flag and the dimensions.  Regardless, you will have great speed benefits if you abandon the vector-of-vector approach and use a single vector.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but is there any reason why you can't just write it directly to linear memory, transposing as you're writing it? You're just swapping the row and column indexes are you not?

```
float *p = linear;
for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
    *(p++) = a[col][row];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there was no misunderstanding, I did something similar but I wanted to access the whole column in just one call but I think it is not possible with vector-vector structures. Thanks for the approach though.